# Extract and diff columns with AWK

Tags: awk

I need to extract the first column from an arbitrary number of files and print the columns with empty lines for the missing entries. Having trouble with the blank lines part. Like so:

```
File1:
Alfa        Something    More stuff
Charlie     Something    More stuff
Delta       Something    More stuff
Echo        Something    More stuff
Foxtrot     Something    More stuff

File2:
Alfa        Something    More stuff
Bravo       Something    More stuff
Echo        Something    More stuff
Foxtrot     Something    More stuff

File3:
Alfa        Something    More stuff
Bravo       Something    More stuff
Charlie     Something    More stuff
Delta       Something    More stuff
Echo        Something    More stuff

Output:
FileName1    FileName2    FileName3
=========    =========    =========
Alfa         Alfa         Alfa
             Bravo        Bravo
Charlie                   Charlie
Delta                     Delta
Echo         Echo         Echo
Foxtrot      Foxtrot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, other than some minor formatting issues:

```
awk '
  { 
    exists[$1] = 1;
    files[$1,ARGIND] = 1;
  }
  END {
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; ++i) {
      printf("%-20s",ARGV[i])
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i=1; i<ARGC; ++i) {
      printf("%-20s","=================")
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (name in exists) {
      for (i=1; i<ARGC; ++i) {
        if (files[name,i]) {
          printf("%-20s",name);
        }
        else {
          printf("%-20s","");
        }
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
' file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: The script gets the headers and length of columns right, but the columns are entirely filled with blanks.

Comment: Strange, I'm not seeing that with my tests.  That is with GNU Awk 4.0.1.

Comment: Solved it. I'm on Debian with mawk by default. Specified gawk and it works. The sorting is all scrambled, but it's easy to re-sort. What's causing the un-sort?

Comment: @user287424: When using the for (x in y) control structure, the results are in no particular order.